# Can't install Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad W510 - freezes at black screen

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation, thinkpad

I can't install Ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64 on my Lenovo Thinkpad W510, using USB. I want a dual boot with Win7 and the latter is already installed.

Installing Ubuntu 9.04 from an old Live CD was possible without any problem, but after creating a bootable USB stick with Universal USB Installer according to Ubuntu instructions, I simply can't get past the menu and I can't do anything from there.

Whether I press `Try without installing`, `Install` or `Check disc...` I get to a black screen with some text on it. I waited for more than 10 minutes to no avail.

[image]

Using <kbd>F6</kbd>, I enabled `nomodeset`, but that did not solve anything. I also checked the ISO md5sum before burning and it was [ok].

Any ideas, please and thank you very much!

**//later edit: fixed by using another USB stick.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It failed to mount the root filesystem from the USB stick. Things to try:

- Check the md5sum on your downloaded image is correct
- Try your USB stick on a different PC
- Try a different USB stick
- Install from a CD

Comment: I had a similar problem. Trying a different USB did the trick

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I checked the md5sum of the ISO file after downloading and it was correct. I will try using a CD instead, although with this stick I managed to successfully install Windows...

Comment: Seems like it worked fine when using another USB. Although my stick was fine since I installed Windows from it. Thanks!